# Solve: $\left(1-\sin2x\right)\left(\cos x-\sin x\right)=1-2\sin^{2}x$

Tags: trigonometry

My attempt:

$$1-2\sin^{2}x=\cos2x$$
Let $$\cos x-\sin x=t$$
Thus, on squaring: $$\sin2x=1-t^{2}$$

I tried simplifying further, but that $cos2x$ is giving me trouble.

Please help!

Comment: What is the original equation you are trying to solve?

Comment: i mean it's the title itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a rewrite, we get $$(\cos x-\sin x)^3 = (\cos x-\sin x)(\cos x+\sin x)$$Can you solve from here?

Comment: I got two solutions, but i'm unable to get the third.

Comment: Which one can you not get?

Comment: $x=2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$ this one

Comment: $\sin\left(2n\pi+\frac\pi2\right)=\cos\left(2n\pi+\frac\pi2\right)$. What does that tell you in the above formula?

Comment: Ok thanks, i found my mistake, all clear now!

Answer (score 0):

$\sin2x=2\cos x\sin x \Rightarrow 1-\sin2x=cos^2x+sin^2x-2\sin x \cos x=(cosx-sinx)^2$

$1-\sin2x=(cosx-sinx)^2 \Rightarrow (1-\sin2x)(cosx-sinx)=(cosx-sinx)^3=1-2\sin^2x$

$(cosx-sinx)^3=1-2\sin^2x=\sin2x$

$cosx-sinx=t \Rightarrow t^3=1-t^2$